# Compiler design

Tags: compiler-optimization

When code is compiled we use symbol table to store data. Is this symbol table containing data is reused in recompilation or new symbol table is created?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The compiler implementor defines whether information is reused. Some compilers do that for optimisation purposes or because there is a special interest (e.g. a function needs to be replaced without modifying the rest of the program).